# Desired label in center of pie chart not rendering DC/D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

With the sample chart/code below, everything renders fine, except for my center of pie chart label indicating total count.  How do I get this text to appear in the middle of my pie chart?

[image]

```
$scope.openRiskCharts = function(){

     $scope.riskChart = new dc.pieChart('#risk-chart', 'risk');
      $scope.riskChart.ordinalColors(["#00b050", "#eeee00", "#ee0000"]);
     var levelCounts = [
                {Level: 'High', Count: 13},
                {Level: 'Med', Count: 43},
                {Level: 'Low', Count: 60}
     ];

     // set crossfilter
     var ndx = crossfilter(levelCounts),
        levelDim  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.Level;}),
        countPerLevel = levelDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.Count});

     var riskchart = document.getElementById('risk-chart'); 


     height = Math.floor(riskchart.offsetHeight) 
      - 2*parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(riskchart, null).getPropertyValue('padding-top'));
     width =  55
        + Math.floor(parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(riskchart, null).width))
      - 2*parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(riskchart, null).getPropertyValue('padding-top'));    

     $scope.riskChart
        .dimension(levelDim)
        .group(countPerLevel)
        .width(width)
        .height(height)
        .radius(Math.round(height/2.0))
        .innerRadius(Math.round(height/5.0))
        .controlsUseVisibility(true)
        .transitionDuration(250);

    //HERE NOTHING APPEARS IN MY CHART CENTER, HOW DO I FIX?    

    var svg = d3.select("svg g:first-of-type"); // select the svg element where you are putting your pie chart.
    svg.enter().append("text") // appent the "text" element
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("142 Open Risks");

   $scope.riskChart.render();


    $scope.openChart = new dc.starChart('#risk-chart', 'blue', 55, 55);
    $scope.openChart.redraw('blue');                            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying my render method (label generation code) to occur in a wrapped pretransition block to account for render time of graph produced proper results.

```
 $scope.riskChart.on('pretransition', function(chart) {             
     d3.select("g.pie-slice-group")
       .append("text") // appent the "text" element
       .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
       .attr('font-size', "15pt")
       .attr('font-weight', "bold")
       .text("142 Risks");     
 });
```